# Merge of different excels using pandas and Dataframes

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 excels that I need to convert to dataframe, apply some operations and then save back as one single Excel which will contain for each Country only rows ‘price1’ and columns ‘Country’, Years (‘2000’ … ‘2017’). All outputs1 should be converted to EUR currency using the FX rates from the file ‘FXrates.csv’ combined with 'Country Code'
The files can be found under
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OfaYvTG5w8Fe5QDFOG5ibD9X052kPbFR
I have tried several things but I'm really stuck here.
This what I tried, but doesn't seem straight to me, and I'm sure there is a better solution

```
df = pd.read_excel("..\Excel1.xlsx",  skiprows=2, sheet_name='sheet1')

cols1 = list(df.columns)
cols1 = [str(x)[:4] for x in cols1]

cols2 = list(df.iloc[0,:])
cols2 = [str(x) for x in cols2]

cols = [x + "_" + y for x,y in zip(cols1,cols2)]
df.columns = cols
#df = df.drop(["Unna_nan"], axis =1)
df = df.drop(["Unna_nan"], axis =1).rename(columns =
                                                      {
                                                          'Time_Country' : 'Country',
                                                          'Unna_Series' : 'Series',
                                                          'Unna_Unit' : 'Unit',
                                                      '2000_nan' : '2000',
                                                       '2001_nan' : '2001',
                                                       '2002_nan':'2002',
                                                       '2003_nan' : '2003',
                                                       '2004_nan' : '2004',
                                                       '2005_nan' : '2005',
                                                       '2006_nan' : '2006',
                                                       '2007_nan' : '2007',
                                                       '2008_nan' : '2008',
                                                       '2009_nan' : '2009',
                                                       '2010_nan' : '2010',
                                                        '2011_nan': '2011',
                                                          '2012_nan' : '2012',
                                                          '2013_nan' : '2013',
                                                          '2014_nan' : '2014',
                                                          '2015_nan' : '2015',
                                                          '2016_nan' : '2016',
                                                          '2017_nan' : '2017'
                                                      }
                                                      )
#drop first and last rows
df.drop(0,inplace=True)
df.drop(df.tail(1).index, inplace=True)


idx = ['Country', 'Series', 'Unit']
df = df.set_index(idx)
df = df.query('Series == "Output1"')`
```

enter code here`

Comment: Please provide the code that you have tried. Also, please refrain from posting links to data. Small subsets should help diagnose any errors and be enough to supply a working example.

Comment: Detail out what you've tried, as well as create an example that shows your problem so people can help. you can create dummy dfs by `df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 3], 'b':[4, 5, 6]})` etc.

Comment: I've added what I tried... See above